# Crear array de rangos de horas en PHP

Tags: php, string, date

Necesito crear un array de rangos de horas en *PHP*.

Seria algo asi como:

```
array[0] = "09:00 - 10:00"
array[1] = "10:00 - 11:00"
array[2] = "11:00 - 12:00"
```

Además, ¿Cómo puedo pasar un formato de fecha y hora de *String* a *Date*? Por ejemplo, sería pasar la cadena `"07/01/2018 09:00"` a *Date*.

Comment: Esto me huele a tarea de inicio de curso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el arreglo te dejo un ejemplo comentado

```
<?php

//Declaras el arreglo donde meteras las fechas
$arr = array();

//Haces un for de 24 horas
for( $i = 0; $i < 24; ){
    //Declaras una sintaxis que la fecha iniciará de media noche más lo que tenga $i en esta vuelta
    $x = "midnight +" . $i . " hour";

    //Lo mismo que $x pero $i más 1 hora de más
    $y = "midnight +" . ($i + 1) . " hour";

    //Paraeas las sintaxis a un formato de hora
    $z = date('H:i:s', strtotime( $x ) ) . ' - ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime( $y ) );

    //Añades el parsing a tu arreglo
    array_push( $arr, $z );

    //Incrementas de 2 en 2,
    $i+=2;
}

print_r( $arr );
?>
```

Para pasar una cadena a `date()` solo falta declarar el formato de salida y pasarle la cadena que tienes en mente (No todas las strings son aceptadas, lee un poco más en [Formatos relativos](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) y [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) )

```
<?php

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('07/01/2018 09:00'));

?>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Pues si, si que es verdad que es de tarea de principio de curso... jajaj pero es para un plugin que estoy realizando en wordpress. El array lo había hecho de otra manera, sin poner el intervalo...